# Creating ArrayLists involving generics and interfaces

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, interface

So I have a generic interface that has two parameters so Type  that I implemented in another class in which I created a constructor. In my main class I am trying to create an arrayList of objects that will use the constructor that I created in the class in which I implemented the generic interface. I just need help in setting up the arrayList for this process. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is the interface:

```
public interface Trip<K, T> {
    public K getPerson();
    public T getLocation();
}
```

This is the implementation:

```
public class TripImpl <K,T> implements Trip <K,T>  {
    private K person;
    private T location;
    private Date dateOfVisit;
    public TripImpl(K person, T locations, Date dateOfVisits){
       person = persons;
       location = locations;
       dateOfVisit = dateOfVisits;
    }
//theres more code with the getters but this is just to show the constructor
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Collect {
   ArrayList <TripImpl> tlist = new ArrayList<TripImpl> ();
       String persons, locatione;
       Date visitd; 
       for (int i =0; i<uPerson.length; i++){
          persons = uPerson[i];
          locatione = uLocation[i];
          visitd = uDate[i];
          TripImpl u<String, String> =  new TripImpl<String, String>(persons, locatione, visitd);
          ulist.add(u);
       }
 }
```

It is giving me an error in the main class with the first line.It says that TripImpl is a raw type and that references to generic type TripImpl should be parameterized

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: And explain where you're stuck.

Comment: Sorry about that I edited it to include the code and where I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
VisitImpl<String, String> u =  new VisitImpl<String, String>(persons, locatione, visitd);
```

Comment: Yes! That helped fix the error I was getting when I tried to create the new Trip Implement. But now there is a problem with my first line : ArrayList <TripImpl> tlist = new ArrayList<TripImpl> (); 

The error says that "TripImpl is a raw type and that references should be parameterized"

Comment: @Plumorane Then do so: `ArrayList<TripImpl<String, String>>`

Comment: Glad to help. If you run in to more trouble, maybe it's best to open another question